# Do not attempt to save variables after Octave crashes

Tags: variables, crash, save, octave, workspace

I am using Octave under Ubuntu.
My Octave script has to make calculations with a big matrix, which I set the size. I want this matrix to be as large as possible within my memory requirements, so I do a few trials to use a reach a large enough matrix.

However, when I exceed the size, of course Ubuntu starts using Swap memory (which makes everything really sluggish) and at this point I want to cancel the script execution. But when I cancel, Octave tries to store my variables (which I dont want to). Below is a CTRL-C example:

```
^C
panic: Interrupt -- stopping myself...
^C
attempting to save variables to 'octave-workspace'...
^C
^C^C
```

This thing can take about half an hour to cancel.

So, the straight question is: how to avoid Octave to try to save the variables to the disk, and just quit instead?

Answer (score 1):

There is a section of the Octave manual, named [Saving Data on Unexpected Exits](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Saving-Data-on-Unexpected-Exits.html) which tells you how to do it. You need to set `crash_dumps_octave_core` to false.

Answer (score 0):

There are also [Octave Startup-Files](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Startup-Files.html#Startup-Files), in which you can put the `crash_dumps_octave_core(0)` if you want that be default.

Also, there is a way to [limit the amount of memory a particular process can use in unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1424/is-there-a-way-to-limit-the-amount-of-memory-a-particular-process-can-use-in-uni).

Finally, there's ctrl-z which follows the kill order more strictly.